# When to get input state: multiple times or one time in a static class?

Tags: xna-4.0, input

Let's say I have these classes:

- Player

Here I want to make the player jump:

```
  current_state_ = Keyboard.GetState();
  if ((current_state_.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) || current_state_.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
       Jump();
```

- Intro scene
- GameOver scene

Here I just want to give the possibility to skip those scenes:

```
  current_state_ = Keyboard.GetState();
  if ((current_state_.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) || current_state_.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
       SkipScene();
```

My question is what is usual done:

- "Asking" for input in every class, or make a static class that asks for input every update, and then you get that value?

  ```
  public static class InputHandler
  {
      private static KeyboardState current_state_;

      public static bool IsSpacePressed()
      {
          return current_key_.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space);
      }

      // Others

      // To be called in game's main loop
      public static void Update(GameTime gametime)
      {
          current_key_ = Keyboard.GetState();
      }
  }
  ```

  I'm worried about that because I thought (don't know if it is correct!) that maybe it is wrong to ask multiple times per update for input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, static properties are a no-no in this case. They should only be used for utility functions (Vector3.Lerp), or for read only variables that will be identical for all instances of a class (Vector3.UnitX).

They introduce issues when trying to synchronize resources because of their nature (anything can access them, so several objects can attempt to update at the same time), and looking up static variables has a significant performance overhead. They also introduce a slippery slop when programming - once you start using them, the longer you go on for, the harder it is to stop.

I would suggest creating one local instance of the keyboards current state in your games main Update method as a local variable (local scope allocation and deallocation are slightly faster than accessing a global variable) and passing it to your Player, IntroScene and GameOverScene classes via a seperate paramater in their update call. This means instead of accessing some global static variable somewhere, you're accessing a local variable variable, which exists in the same scope (local scopes get searched first for variables before global scopes). Also, it means you only fetch the keyboard state once per update, further saving on performance. Given the number of update calls a second, a little bit of performance gain can go a long way

However, it does boil down to your preference in the end. If you feel statics are the best way to go, then who are we to stop you?

Some further reading, if you are interested.

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/186915-Declaring-a-Variables-Locally-Vs-Globally-Effect-on-Performance

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924223/static-vs-non-static-class-members